# Sum and Product of different row and columns between tables in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-function

I've a requirement where I have to do a bit of computation in/on the database (i.e., in SQL query). Before explaining my requirement, let me explain the table structures:

**Relationship Table**

```
Client(k)   PolicyCvg(k)        Relationship
----------------------------------------------------
RAJ         1234  00        OWNER
RAJ         1234  01        INSURED
BRAD        ASDF  00        OWNER
RAJ         ASDF  01        INSURED
BRAD        ASDF  02        INSURED
BRAD        ASDF  03        INSURED
BRAD        ASDF  04        INSURED
BRAD        ABCDEF00        OWNER
BRAD        ABCDEF01        INSURED
RAJ         ABCDEF01        INSURED
```

**Policy Table**

```
Policy(k)   Mode        MaxCvgNum
------------------------------------------
1234        02      03
ASDF        06      04
ABCDEF      01      02
```

**Coverage Table**

```
Policy(k)   Cvg(k)      Amount      Tax     Risk
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1234        01      500.00      2.00        HIGH
ASDF        01      200.00      0.75        LOW
ASDF        02      300.00      0.76        LOW
ASDF        03      400.00      0.26        HIGH
ASDF        03      500.00      0.78        LOW
ABCDEF      01      1000.00     3.15        MEDIUM
ABCDEF      02      100.00      0.03        LOW
```

My requirement is to sum up `Amount` and `Tax` in the Coverage table in one row and multiply it with the `Mode` of the respective `Policy` in the Policy Table; let's call the result `AMT`.

Then sum up all `AMT` (`SUM (AMT)`) for all the rows in the Coverage table.
To Select a particular policy row from the Coverage/Policy Table, I would first fetch the policies from the Relationship table where 'BRAD' is Owner.

So far I've been only able to come up with the below queries for each table:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(PolicyCvg,1,6) AS Policy
FROM Relationship
WHERE RELATIONSHIP = 'OWNER' AND CLIENT = 'BRAD'

SELECT Mode
FROM Policy
WHERE Policy IN (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(PolicyCvg,1,6) AS Policy
    FROM Relationship
    WHERE RELATIONSHIP = 'OWNER' AND CLIENT = 'BRAD'
)

SELECT Amount,Tax
FROM Coverage
WHERE Policy IN (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(PolicyCvg,1,6) AS Policy
    FROM Relationship
    WHERE RELATIONSHIP = 'OWNER' AND CLIENT = 'BRAD'
)
```

My Input would be the Client, so first fetch the Policies from that client from the Relationship table where the relationship is OWNER.

Next fetch the Mode from the Policy table for the selected policies and also fetch the sum of Amount and Tax for these policies from the Coverage table.

Now multiply the Sum obtained from Coverage table with the Mode from the Policy Table. Add up all such products obtained for all Policies and give it as Output as TotalRisk.

Now I'm confused if to build a complex joint query or build an Oracle Function for my requirement and I've very little knowledge in both the fields.

Could you people please help me out?

Comment: I would suggest creating a function and returning the desired output from the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Oracle, you could try the following:

```
select
   r.client
  ,sum(c.amount) * max(to_number(case when p.status = 'Pending' then '0' else p.mode end)) as amount_x_mode
  ,sum(c.tax) * max(to_number(case when p.status = 'Pending' then '0' else p.mode end)) as tax_x_mode
  ,sum(c.amount) * max(to_number(case when p.status = 'Pending' then '0' else p.mode end)) + sum(c.tax) *  max(to_number(case when p.status = 'Pending' then '0' else p.mode end)) as amount_tax_x_mode
from relationship r

inner join policy p
  on trim(p.policy) = trim(SUBSTRING(r.PolicyCvg,1,6))

inner join coverage c
  on trim(c.policy) = trim(SUBSTRING(r.PolicyCvg,1,6))

where r.relationship = 'OWNER'
  and r.client = 'BRAD'

group by r.client
;
```

However I have a feeling you may want to include cvg in the join to the Coverage table.  If so let me know and I can adjust the query for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is working though I need to add the two fields "amount_x_mode" and "tax_x_mode" finally and show it as a single value I'm trying to add the two fields but not able to.
Also I do not need to include cvg in the query as my expectation is to calculate for all coverage records if the policy is present in Relationship table. Though I've a additional set of requirement which says if the Policy is present in Policy Table and as a status of "Pending" (New Column being introduced) then such policies should not be taken for calculation from the Coverage table.

Comment: Could you kindly help me out here.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my original answer above.  Please kindly mark it as the correct solution.